# Trying to combine two IF statements together in google sheets

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, nested-if

I am basically trying to check if column F has a specific value and along with if column G also has a specific value, then return something. My code looked like this

=IF(F:F="Naveen",IF(G:G="YTS","working"),"not working")

This is returning "not working", even though both the specific values are present.

[Sheet image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rxiV.jpg)

Can someone please help?

Comment: If the below answer doesn't work for you, can you please share a copy of your sheet?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do comparison with a range using `=`

`IF(COUNTIF(F:F,"Naveen")>0,IF(COUNTIF(G:G,"YTS")>0,"working","not working"),"not working")`

or

`IF(AND(COUNTIF(F:F,"Naveen")>0,COUNTIF(G:G,"YTS")>0),"working","not working")`

Answer (score 0):

use in row 2:

```
=INDEX(IF(F2:F="Naveen"; IF(G2:G="YTS"; "working"); "not working"))
```